# Haskell, type mismatch between floor, toRational, and logBase

Tags: haskell, type-mismatch

This is really bugging me. I want to find the largest m such that 2^m < n.
This is what I did:

```
m = floor $ toRational $ logBase 2 n
```

GHCI complains:

```
No instance for (Floating Int) arising from a use of ‘logBase’
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘logBase 2 n’
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘toRational $ logBase 2 n’
In the expression: floor $ toRational $ logBase 2 n
```

I don't understand why, since:

```
*Main> :t logBase 
logBase :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
*Main> :t toRational 
toRational :: Real a => a -> Rational
*Main> :t floor 
floor :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b
```

`logBase` returns a `Floating`, while `toRational` accepts a `Real`: this must work, since how can a `Floating` not be a `Real`. Then `toRational` returns a `Rational`, while `floor` accepts a `RealFrac`. I don't know what that is (I tried looking it up with `:info RealFrac` with little useful output), but how can a `Rational` not be a `RealFrac`?

The error has it with `Floating Int`, can you shed light on this for me? As a second question, how can I get more info about weird types like `RealFrac` inside GHCI? As I said `:info RealFrac` wasn't very helpful to me.

Comment: Use fromIntegeral n instead of n, and skip the toRational, I suspect, but I haven't checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `n` is type `Int` which has no instance for `Floating`. You can use `fromIntegral`:

```
m = floor $ toRational $ logBase 2 (fromIntegral n)
```

Comment: Wow, I always over-analyze and drown in an inch of water... FF